# Cambiar el contexto (URL Root) de un proyecto web en eclipse

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Estoy con un proyecto, que al correrlo en el eclipse lo deja escuchando en `http://localhost:8080/nombre_del_proyecto/`. Lo que quiero es que ahora corra en `http://localhost:8080/otro_nombre/`.

¿Dónde se cambia el nombre de la app o URL root en la que corre el proyecto? Porque tengo 500 .xml que probé cambiando y no se refleja ningún cambio.

Comment: ¿Qué servidor de aplicaciones estás utilizando? e.g. WebSphere, WebLogic, NetWeaver, *Tomcat*...

Comment: Hola! Ahí agregué la etiqueta, estoy usando Tomcat

Comment: Estas usando maven?

Comment: Sisi, uso Maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede especificar la ruta de contexto de la aplicación Web para Tomcat a través del archivo `context.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/otro_nombre"/>
```

Sin embargo, [image: icon] eclipse ignora este archivo y considera el valor configurado en las propiedades del proyecto. Ver "Properties for nombre_del_proyecto" > "Web Project Settings" > "Context root".

[image: eclipse]

Antes de que Tomcat haga el despliegue, [image: icon] eclipse edita el archivo `server.xml` ubicado en, por ejemplo, `/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config/` y agrega una línea similar a:

```xml
<Context docBase="nombre_del_proyecto" 
         path="/otro_nombre" 
         reloadable="true" 
         source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:nombre_del_proyecto"/>
```

Una vez que todos los archivos están listos, se copian a la carpeta correspondiente del espacio de trabajo, e.g. `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps`.

Comment: Excelente! Mil gracias! Hice lo del Web Proyect Settings, limpie el Tomcat, lo reinicié y salió andando!

Answer (score 1):

Debes de modificar en Tomcat la configuración de contexto en el archivo `server.xml` si no lo has modificado debería estar en `[tomcat dir]/config/`, en el debes modificar el atributo path por la ruta que le deseas colocar

```
<Context docBase="nombre_del_proyecto" path="/otro_nombre" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:nombre_del_proyecto"/>
```