# Dos aplicaciones war pueden correr simultaneamente en el mismo root context

Tags: java, web, java-ee, jboss-eap, war

Quiero que mi aplicación se ejecute en un contexto diferente al nombre del proyecto, para eso encontre esta solución en el foro 
[Cambiar el contexto (URL Root) de un proyecto web en eclipse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98914/cambiar-el-contexto-url-root-de-un-proyecto-web-en-eclipse?rq=1)
eso esta bien, pero mi duda es si yo tengo dos aplicaciones independientes (proyecto1.war y proyecto2.war) estas pueden usar el mismo contexto ejemplo

```
www.dominio.com/MyContext/proyecto1

www.dominio.com/MyContext/proyecto2
```

y que debo tener encuenta para hacerlo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Si se puede, nosotros en un cliente por ejemplo tenemos unos 20 servicios y todos tienen una ruta como esta `[ip]:[puerto]/[context]/[proyecto]` el como: Lo hacemos a través del [WebLogic de Oracle](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic)

Answer (score 0):

La personalización del enlace se gestiona desde el propio servidor de aplicaciones (si ofrece esa funcionalidad) o bien usando "**Apache HTTP Server**" como proxy. Puedes hacer redirecciones tipo:

```
http://servidor.com  >>> http://servidorTomcat:8080/appPrincipal-pro

http://test.servidor.com  >>> http://servidorTomcat:8080/appPrincipal-test

http://servidor.com/blogs/pepe  >>> http://servidorPHP:80/webs/blogPepe
```

No recuerdo cómo se configuraba. Creo que le llaman Reverse Proxy:

https://www.nanotutoriales.com/como-configurar-un-reverse-proxy-o-gateway-en-apache

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html